# How to compute the homology of two sphere with two handles

Tags: homology-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

How to compute the homology of two sphere with two handles??
here is the figure
[**two sphere with two handles**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCl76.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please check out [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/) on MathSE query guidelines, for this question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.